# Simple groups from Orthogonal groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups

I am trying to understand simple groups arising from finite orthogonal groups; these are complicated among groups of Lie type in the sense that one should be careful about characteristic of field (even/odd), dimension of space (even/odd) and type of bilinear form. It also requires (as most books write) that one have to pass to quadratic forms from bilinear form according to characteristic of field. I don't know whether we can stick only to non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form.

I tried to understand this in the following way in which  I do not specify characteristic of field, dimension of space, structure of bilinear form etc., and I want to know whether it is correct.

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over a finite field $F$.

Let $(x,y)\mapsto B(x,y)\in F$ be a bilinear form on $V$ such that it is symmetric and non-degenerate  (i.e. $B(x,y)=B(y,x)$ and $B(x,y)=0$ for all $y$ implies $x=0$.)

Let $$G=\{T:V\rightarrow V: B(Tx,Ty)=B(x,y) \forall x,y\in V\}.$$

Then $G$ is a subgroup of $GL(V)$. Consider subgroup $[G,G]$ and then the quotient 
$$[G,G] / (center).$$
This quotient group is simple with some exceptions on dimension and characteristic of the field. Excluding exceptions, this covers all simple groups arising from orthogonal groups; am I right?

Comment: You might also want to consider symplectic groups, which arise from a non-symmetric bilinear form.

Comment: Bemte: sorry, for them there is not so much complication as it is for orthogonal groups. (Many times I left reading theory of them when I moved from one condition to other, here and there,...)

Comment: If you want a complete overview, you should take a look at the book "the geometry of the classical groups" by Donald Taylor. He covers all these groups and also proves which one of them are simple. He furter also gives alternative definitions in characteristic two for $P\Omega$, which is (in odd characteristic) the simple group you described here.